# calling super.equals() in derived class while overriding equals

Tags: java, inheritance, equals, overriding

I have a base class with age and name as instance members and derived class with bonus. I am overriding equals in Derived class. I know how equals works in Java when there is a single base class. But I am not able to understand how it works in case of inheritance. I want to check if two derived objects are equal.

I was expecting the output to be 
This class = Base, Other class = Derived 
instead the output is 
This class = Derived, Other class = Derived

What is super in equals method of derived class exactly doing?Isnt it referring to Base?

```
<br/>

public class Base{

    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Base(int age, String name){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherBase){

        //Check if both the references refer to same object
        if(this == otherBase){
            return true;
        }

        if(otherBase == null){
            return false;
        }

        System.out.println("This class       ="+this.getClass().getCanonicalName()+", Other class = "+otherBase.getClass().getCanonicalName());

        if(this.getClass() != otherBase.getClass()){
            return false;
        }

        if(! (otherBase instanceof Base)){
            return false;
        }

        Base other = (Base) otherBase;

        return this.age == other.age && this.name.equals(other.name);
       }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Derived d1 = new Derived(10,6,"shri");
        Derived d2 = new Derived(10,5, "shri");
        if(d1.equals(d2)){
            System.out.println("Equal");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        }
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{

    private int bonus;

    public int getBonus(){
        return bonus;
    }

    public Derived(int bonus, int age, String name){
        super(age, name);
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherDerived){
        if(!(super.equals(otherDerived))){
            return false;
        }

        Derived derived = (Derived) otherDerived;
        return bonus == derived.bonus;
    }
}
```

Comment: This test `if(! (otherBase instanceof Base)){` is unnecessary because of the one above it: `if(this.getClass() != otherBase.getClass())` You've already made sure it is exactly the same class, so it can't not be a descendant of `Base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So the `equals()` method is implemented correctly and it works in the following way**:

1. delegate the comparison of the `age` and `name` to the `Base` class
2. if it is not the same, return false
3. otherwise compare the value of the `bonus` field in the `Derived` class

**The call of `super.equals()` will call the `equals()` from super class (`Base`), but `this` still represents the real instance, e.g. `Derived` in your case.**

Comment: So basically calling super.equals(otherDerived) is as good as d1 object calling equals method of Base class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by d1?

Comment: Derived d1 = new Derived(10,6,"shri") from main method

Comment: Yes, correct. It will literally call equals() from Base class.

Answer (score 1):

> What is super in equals method of derived class exactly doing?Isnt it referring to Base?

`super` is used to call the *overriden* equals method (the one defined in `Base`). More generally, `super` references the superclass of the type in which it is used, so in this case yes it refers to `Base`. However, the referenced object's type ***at runtime*** is still `Derived`.

In the `Base#equals()` method, the expression `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` returns the name of the class for the object at runtime. Even if the expression is called in the `equals` method of the base class, the actual type is `Derived`. This is what the `getClass` method does as mentioned in the Javadocs:

> Returns the *runtime* class of this Object.

If you ever need to get the name of the superclass, you can use `this.getClass().getSuperclass().getCanonicalName()`.